# PHP code inside AJAX to POST

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to echo PHP variable `$last_id` to AJAX to pass it onto PHP `$_POST`. May be I can skip AJAX all together and just transfer variable inside `$_POST`. Do I have to use `echo json_encode`?

Here is my code to see what I'm trying to accomplish here (any help appreciated):

**registration.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
require 'connect.php';

$sql = "INSERT INTO table (username, password) VALUES ('".$_POST["username"]."','".$_POST["password"]."')";

if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
$last_id = mysqli_insert_id($con);
    echo $last_id;
?>
```

**myScript.js**

```
// ----AJAX Post to PHP----->
function ajax_post(ele,div){
// XMLHttpRequest object
var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();

// variables send to PHP file
var url = "insert.php";
var userId = "<?php echo $last_id; ?>";
var vars = "userId="+userId;
hr.open("POST", url, true);
hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
        var return_data = hr.responseText;
        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = return_data;
        }
    }
}
```

**insert.php**

```
<?php
require 'connect.php';

$userId = $_POST['userId'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO table2 (userId) 
VALUES ('$userId')";
?>
```

Comment: Dont forget to put &amp character before userId : var vars = "imgName="+SOMETHING_IS_MISSING_HERE+"&userId="+userId;

Comment: Couple things, don't add variables directly into the query like `"INSERT INTO table (username, password) VALUES ('".$_POST["username"]."','".$_POST["password"]."')"` or this `"INSERT INTO table2 (userId) 
VALUES ('$userId')"`. This is a security flaw.

Comment: Also, your `myScript.js` can not parse php so this `<?php echo $last_id; ?>` can not work.

Comment: @ Ashraf thanks I forgot to delete that. I have edited it..

Comment: If you make a function that your registration page can write using your ajax function, you will probably find it working. Something like `echo "<script>ajax_post('{$lastid}');</script>"` That is not going to work as is because the function doesn't use the parameter like that, but that would work (the approach) if you are trying to send the php variable across ajax.

Comment: Also, closing out PHP files with `?>` is pointless and defies [modern coding standards](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/).

Comment: @Sergey M. this will not work `var userId = "<?php echo $last_id; ?>";` in myscript.js just because your $last_id is in different file, to make it work your put myscript.js code in registration page then it will work.

Comment: @JiteshNK is there any way to keep it separate? Its going to be long code...

Comment: I just want to point out that questions like these are exactly why frameworks were invented.  In Slim, for example, he could dynamically generate the contents of `myScript.js`.

Comment: One last comment, you should not be storing passwords in plaintext. You should use `password_hash()` / `password_verify()` or compatible library.

Comment: @Rasclatt thanks I will take it for consideration.

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is how you can pass php variable into external js file,

```
<?php
$last_id= "Red";
?>
<script type="text/javascript">var color = "<?= $last_id?>";</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js"></script>
```

Try and let me know

Comment: This is what I get in my database <?= $last_id?>  I need mysqli_insert_id data to be transferred in my case...

Comment: @ Sergey M. sorry typo `<script type="text/javascript">var color = "<?php echo $last_id?>";</script>`

Answer (score 0):

As your posted code you are missing `hr.send(vars)` and as I am seeing your `$last_id` is coming after registration. So i suggest you to store that value in session then use and after ajax call destroy the session if needed.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
require 'connect.php';

$sql = "INSERT INTO table (username, password) VALUES ('".$_POST["username"]."','".$_POST["password"]."')";

if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
$last_id = mysqli_insert_id($con);
session_start();
$_SESSION['last_id'] = $last_id;
?>

// ----AJAX Post to PHP----->
function ajax_post(ele,div){
// XMLHttpRequest object
var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();

// variables send to PHP file
var url = "insert.php";
var vars = "userId=<?php echo $_SESSION['last_id']; ?>";
hr.open("POST", url, true);
hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
    var return_data = hr.responseText;
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = return_data;
    }
   }
}
hr.send(vars);
```